# start at the top of the page when changing page

Tags: nested, scrollview

ı have a problem about scrollview.
my project about a newspaper.my problem about : I want to start at the
top of the page when changing page.
 scrollview have 8 news.ı want to beginning at the top of the text on
the page when change 2. or 3. or.. news..

please help me about it.because ı  need to deliver the project on Monday.for this reason ı
must do today or tomorrow.
code of project in here

```
myScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
myScrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
myScrollview.scrollEnabled =YES;
myScrollview.clipsToBounds = NO;
myScrollview.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
myScrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myScrollview.delegate = self;

NSInteger viewcount=4;
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo4.png"],nil];

for (int i = 0; i <viewcount; i++)
{
    CGFloat x = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    subView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [subView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    subView.clipsToBounds = NO;    // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    subView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];
    aImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 900);
    [aImageView setTag:viewcount];
    [subView addSubview:aImageView];
    [subView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(aImageView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height)];
    subView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    subView.maximumZoomScale = 9;
    subView.delegate = self;
    [subView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    subView.contentSize = aImageView.frame.size;
    [myScrollview addSubview:subView];
}

myScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*viewcount,self.view.frame.size.height);


[self.view addSubview:myScrollview];
```

https://biliyomusunuz.com